# Браузеры не обновляют стили css

Tags: css, вёрстка, google-chrome, sass

Возникла следующая проблема. Верстаю в VS code изменения в life server. До поры до времени все было нормально, теперь же не применяется ни один стиль css, а именно, когда меняю свойство background, фон остается прежним.

В панели разработчика гугл disable cache выставил, через ctrl+f5 аналогично пробовал. Но что самое интересное, если запускать в другом браузере, то показывается совершенно другой фон, который был до того фона, который я хочу установить.  Кто с таким сталкивался, что делать?

P.S. То есть на лайф сервере один кэш, а если открывать в браузере просто index.html, то там другой кэш.  Как такое возможно?

Comment: Попробуйте очистить всю историю с этим сервером и файлом в целом
Или в крайнем случае, зайдите через режим инкогнито

Comment: ctrl+shift+r? 
У меня иногда такое же бывает. Эта комбинация помогает.

Comment: пробовал, странно но нет не помогло

Comment: хм. Может в life server какой-то заглюк....

Comment: да, возможно, но тогда почему если открываю не в лайве совсем другая картинка получается, которую я так же не ставил, но которая видимо была когда я тестил стили. Вообще просто вынос мозга с этой хней

Comment: а попробуй на другом запусти.OpenServer, например.

Comment: Попробуйте полный путь к файлу css. <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">

Answer (score 0):

В Хроме нажмите Ctrl Shift J (on Windows) для открития панели разработчика(Developer Tools)  , во вкладке Network поставте галочку Disable cache.

В панели разработчика(Developer Tools) можно открить вкладку Elements и посмотреть какие классы css подключены. Если не видно классов єто означает что ваш css файл не подключен.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Тоже столкнулся с этим. Сделал

```
disable cache
```

и удалил все, что там накопилось. и нормально обновилось с уже измененными настройками из `*.css`.